# Display Information to the UI

Tags: xamarin.forms

So what I have been trying is this: After successful registration the user gets a Message in the interface to show that Registration was successful. My first method was I declared a Message variable and use Data Binding to bind the result to a label in my *RegisterPage.xaml*. That failed because whether the message is successful or not the label is not showing. So I commented out using a label and tried DisplayAlert but DisplayAlert is giving an error- does not exist in the current context.
Please help, still learning.

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    private readonly DataService dataService = new DataService();
    public string Email  { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }


    public ICommand RegisterCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(async () =>
            {
                var isRegistered = await dataService.RegisterUserAsync(Email, Password, ConfirmPassword);

                Settings.Username = Email;
                Settings.Password = Password;

                if (isRegistered)
                {

                    //DisplayAlert( "Alert" , "Registered", "OK");
                    //Message = "Registered Successfully :)";
                    // DependencyService.Get<Toast>().Show("You have registered succefully");
                    Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new EntryPage());
                }

                else
                {
                    Message = " Retry Later :(";
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`DisplayAlert` is part of the `Page` class. If you want to display an alert from a view model (there are many results on Google), you'd call a method like:

```cs
private async Task DisplayGenericDialog(string title, string message)
{
   await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(title, message, "OK");
}
```